# System.TypeLoadException: Cannot instantiate transport [Akka.Remote.AkkaIOTransport.AkkaIOTransport, Akka.Remote.AkkaIOTransport].

Tags: akka.net, akka-io

I came across this error while trying out the AKKA.NET IO following this tutorial:

http://getakka.net/docs/IO#akka-i-o

I get this error:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Cannot instantiate transport [Akka.Remote.AkkaIOTransport.AkkaIOTransport, Akka.Remote.AkkaIOTransport].
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by the fact that the IO package has been refactored so instead of having this HOCON configuration:

```
        transport-class = "Akka.Remote.AkkaIOTransport.AkkaIOTransport, Akka.Remote.AkkaIOTransport"
```

you should have this:

```
                  transport-class = "Akka.Remote.Transport.AkkaIO.AkkaIOTransport, Akka.Remote"
```